# Create a Data Warehouse with the database on SQL Developer

Tags: database, oracle, data-warehouse

I have a database in SQL Developer which pull data from an ERP tool and I would like to create a Data warehouse in order to connect it then to PowerBI.

It's my first time that I am doing all this process from the beginning so I am not so experienced.

So where are you suggesting to create the Data Warehouse (I was thinking on SSMS) and how can I connect it with PowerBI ?

My Data Warehouse will consist from some View of my tables and some Joins to get some data in the structure that I want since it is not possible to change anything in the DB.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A "data warehouse" is just a database. The distinction is really more about the commonly used schema design, in the sense that a warehouse is often built along the lines of a [star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_schema) or [snowflake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowflake_schema) design.

So if you already have a database that is extracting data from your ERP, there is nothing to stop you from pointing PowerBI directly at that and performing some analytics etc.  If your intention is to start with this database, and then clone/extract/load this data into a ***new*** database which is a star/snowflake schema, then that's a much bigger exercises.

Comment: Yes actually I connected this database in PowerBI in order to create some live visuals and for the rest of the reports that i will create i will create some views in order to transform the data in the format that i want (some joins, some calculations etc.) before connect to Power BI.